# Query relationships efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's assume the tables and data

```
CREATE TABLE #tA ( id int, fieldA varchar(16))
CREATE TABLE #tB ( idA int, id int, fieldB varchar(16))
CREATE TABLE #tC ( idB int, id int, fieldC varchar(16))

INSERT into #tA VALUES (1, 'A1'), (2, 'A2')
INSERT into #tB VALUES (1, 1, 'A1-B1'), (1, 2, 'A1-B2'), (2, 3, 'A2-B1')
INSERT into #tC VALUES (1, 1, 'A1-B1-C1'), (2, 2, 'A1-B2-C1'), (2, 3, 'A1-B2-C2'), (3, 4, 'A2-B1-C1')
```

I can query the complete relationships with all the data with

```
SELECT A.fieldA, B.fieldB, C.fieldC
FROM #tA as A
JOIN #tB as B ON b.idA=A.id
JOIN #tC as C ON c.idB=b.id
```

and the result is

```
fieldA  fieldB  fieldC
A1      A1-B1   A1-B1-C1
A1      A1-B2   A1-B2-C1
A1      A1-B2   A1-B2-C2
A2      A2-B1   A2-B1-C1
```

On the client side I want/need to build an object model like

```
{
   name: "A1",
   Bs: [
     {
        name: 'A1-B1',
        Cs: [{name: 'A1-B1-C1'}]
     },
     {
        name: 'A1-B2',
        Cs: [{name: 'A1-B2-C1'}, {name: 'A1-B2-C2'}]
...
```

Of course the actual tables have more fields and rows and I therefore would like to reduce the overhead on the network for sending all the fields multiple times.
It would be sufficient (and actually easier to build an object model) if the data was returned from the sql server like

```
fieldA  fieldB  fieldC
A1      A1-B1   A1-B1-C1
null    A1-B2   A1-B2-C1
null    null    A1-B2-C2
A2      A2-B1   A2-B1-C1
```

That is only if the "parent" has changed, write the value(s) of that "parent" table to the result set, otherwith set those fields to null.

Is that (efficiently) possible with SQL Server (2014/2016)? Maybe some built-in functions for that?
Or is that even built into the network protocol sql-server<->.net-driver?

Comment: "I therefore would like to reduce the overhead on the network for sending all the fields multiple times".  This is probably a useless attempt at optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do that to your queries, but since the final goal is to produce a hierarchical object model, your time and effort would be much better spent researching object/relational mappers which automate most of the heavy lifting. What's available depends on the client application's programming language; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) has a list covering several.